# Load test for a web server

Tags: python

I have to write python script to perform load test for thttpd server. i need to test like "wat happens if 500 users accesing the server at a time" . i'm in need of some input to implement this..

Comment: Step 1.  Write some code.  Step 2.  Post the code and ask questions about the code.  We're not going to write your load test for you.  Hint.  Use `urllib2` to make requests.  Use `subprocess` to spawn 500 processes all making requests at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great chart of python load testing frameworks available at

https://web.archive.org/web/20141106040743/http://pycheesecake.org/wiki/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy

or a more official list at:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy#Web_Testing_Tools

Comment: mentioned website does not exist anymore and is replaced by blogvertisement. Is https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy#Fuzz_Testing_Tools providing the same ?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, just updated the links -- and yes the python wiki has a pretty similar list

Answer (score 1):

Check [Locust.io](http://locust.io/) . We have our tests in Python and it just made sense to go with it. It rather simple but gets the job done writing only python.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at using [Multi-Mechanize](http://code.google.com/p/multi-mechanize/) as that allows you to do load testing with Python and is quite good!